# django rest framework method 'DELETE' not allowed because DefaultRouter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is my first project with Django and I am having a bit of trouble with the URLs.

I have a customer model and I created the `ModelViewSet` for it so I can retrieve, delete and update the models in the database.

To get all the basic URLs I used `rest_framework.routers.DefaultRouter` and registered the `CustomerViewSet` to it like so:

```py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'customers', CustomerViewSet, basename='customers')
```

And then registered the URLs like so:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls), name="customers"),
]
```

My problem is that I need to add a new URL for deleting all the customers in the database.

I tried adding it like so:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls), name="customers"),
    path('customers/', deleteAllCustomers, name='deleteAll'),
]
```

Where `deleteAllCustomers` is a function decorated with `api_view(['DELETE']`.

When I try to call this URL (using Postman), I get 405 error (method 'DELETE' not allowed).

From what I understand, it happens because that URL is already assigned by the `DefaulteRouter` for PUT/POST methods.

I tried adding a `destroy` function to my `CustomerViewSet`, but it is only called when deleting one instance (with primary key passed in the URL).

I haven't found a way to make the URL work and wasn't able to find any similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Oluwatomisin Omotosho James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10522399/oluwatomisin-omotosho-james) for helping me with this.

I forgot to mention that in my case I need the URL `/customers/` to support both the `POST` and `DELETE` methods.

So I changed the `deleteAllCustomers` function to also handle the `POST` request.
(And like they suggested, reordering the `urlpatterns` array)

The code now works great

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code snippet. The url path for `deleteAllCustomers` and `CustomerViewSet` are the same i.e `.../customers`

I think your app urls.py file should look like this:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from customers import views


router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('', views.CustomerViewSet,
                basename="customers")

app_name = 'customers'

urlpatterns = [
    path('customers/', deleteAllCustomers, name='deleteAll'),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    
]
```

The order of the url patterns is important.

Your views.py file for `CustomerViewSet` should look like this to support: GET,CREATE,PUT,PATCH,RETRIEVE,DELETE

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, mixins, permissions, authentication


class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet,
                       mixins.ListModelMixin,
                       mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                       mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                       mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                       mixins.DestroyMixin
                       ):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated)

    serializer_class = serializers.CustomerModelSerializer
    queryset = models.Customers.objects.all()
```

Then you can set up your `deleteAllCustomers` views how you want to.

Comment: It works, but now the `POST` request returns 405...

Comment: oh really sorry about that I missed out to mixins for POST request. Let me update my answer.Thanks

Comment: Add `mixins.CreateModelMixin,` to the `CustomerViewSet`.You can check my answer have made the required changes

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work. I guess that it is because the URLs for the `POST` and `DELETE `are the same, django takes only the first `APIView`...
I think I need to change my `deleteAllCustomers` method to also handle `POST` request

Comment: is the 405 for the POST request on the `deleteAllCustomers` views?

Comment: When i use the URL `/customers/` with `DELETE` method it works and invokes the `deleteAllCustomers` function. But when I call this URL with `POST` method it returns 405 (although it should have been handled by the `CustomerViewSet`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243573/discussion-between-oluwatomisin-omotosho-james-and-sagiziv).